# Placing div after click between two other without moving them

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is: I click a button, div appears and it is placed between other two containers without moving them.

So in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/26/ I will only have box 1 and box 3 visible, but when I click button, box 2 appears between these two containers like in the fiddle, but without moving them. I want help only with CSS part.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box-3">Box 3</div>
  <button class="cta">
    Click
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-1{
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.box-2{
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.box-3{
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

Comment: You really need JavaScript for this. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Using visibility:hidden keeps the space occupied. On click, the visibility becomes "visible".

```js
$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(".box-2").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

```css
.box-1{
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.box-2{
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.box-3{
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box-3">Box 3</div>
  <button class="cta">
    Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with JavaScript what you want can be done easily using JS.

What you need to do is adding the code block below to the end of your html code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("box-2");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Then your button's code will change to:

```
<button class="cta" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Now when you click on the button your div will show up and when you click again it will disappear.

Finally your whole code will look like below:

```
<style>
.box-1{
background-color: gray;
padding: 20px 40px;
}

#box-2{
background-color: darkgray;
padding: 20px 40px;
display: none;
}

.box-3{
background-color: gray;
padding: 20px 40px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<div class="box-1">Box 1</div>
<div id="box-2">Box 2</div>
<div class="box-3">Box 3</div>
<button class="cta" onclick="myFunction()">
Click
</button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("box-2");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

> By the way, I used internal CSS. If your CSS is External you can remove the codes between `<style>` and `</style>` tags.

Answer (score -1):

I had only problem with CSS, when I put box 2 between box 1 and box 3 they changed position. I eventually solved the problem with position: absolute. Thanks everyone for answers though.